# как обьединить два селектора в один?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как обьединить два селектора:

```
const divBody = document.querySelector('#exampleModal').querySelector('.modal-body');
```

в один селектор?

Answer (score 4):

```
const divBody = document.querySelector('#exampleModal .modal-body');
```